# Unity3d. Handles.ScaleValueHandle changes size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with `Handles.ScaleValueHandle` method.

This method changes size that I pass to it.

```
float newRadius = Handles.ScaleValueHandle(cCollider.radius, pos, handleRot, cCollider.radius, MyCircleCap, 0);
// cCollider.radius == 0.117120504f
```

But in my `MyCircleCap` I have another size:

```
private void MyCircleCap(int controlID, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, float size)
{
    // size == 0.017568076f
    Handles.CircleCap(controlID, position, rotation, size);
}
```

So the size of the circle is wrong.
I have tried to do something like this:

```
    sircleCapSize = cCollider.radius; // save value in separate variable
    float newRadius = Handles.ScaleValueHandle(cCollider.radius, pos, handleRot, cCollider.radius, MyCircleCap, 0);
}

float sircleCapSize;
private void MyCircleCap(int controlID, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, float size)
{
    // using saved size in variable `sircleCapSize`
    // instead of size from parameters
    Handles.CircleCap(controlID, position, rotation, sircleCapSize);
}
```

The circle now look fine, but i can't touch it by my mouse. That is because of i lied that circle are large. In fact, it small, and i can touch it only if i click on center of circle. So i tried another:

```
float magicNumber = 8f;
float newRadius = Handles.ScaleValueHandle(cCollider.radius, pos, handleRot, cCollider.radius * magicNumber, MyCircleCap, 0);
```

Now it work. Size approximately correct. But who now, maybe some day unity team will fix this bug (if it is a bug, actually) and i will have wrong size again.

Can anyone say me how to do it right?

I use Unity version:

> Version 5.1.1f1 (2046fc06d4d8) Personal
>   Fri, 27 Mar 2015 09:26:51 GMT
>   Branch: 5.1/release

**UPDATE 1 (adding screenshots):**

I'm trying to add my own collider radius handle:

[image: Image1]

I call `Handles.ScaleValueHandle( , , , cCollider.radius, MyCircleCap, );` method, and I pass an exact size of my collider (cCollider.radius) into it:

[image]

1. Method that calls my 'MyCircleCap'
2. Value that i pass to `Handles.ScaleValueHandle` as a size

But `ScaleValueHandle` changes size, so in my `MyCircleCap` i have another size:

[image]

1. Now, I am in my 'MyCircleCap' method
2. Value that i receive as a size

How to prevent size changing?

Comment: Probably because it's hard to understand what you want exactly. Screenshots would help a lot - care to add them?

Comment: Screenshots of both editor and transform values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the ratio size/cCollider.radius = 0.15, so if you change magicNumber to 1/.15f size would be equal to cCollider.radius without the need of a temporary variable.

Comment: Where I can change this value? Or can I think of it as it is a constant?

Comment: It is a constant. Size is simply multiplied by 0.15f.

Comment: Can you say, please, where it is documented?

Answer (score 1):

Does the GameObject of your cCollider Component is scalled differently than Vector3.one ?
If so reset it to Vector3.one

The constant 0.15 from Pluto is not documented because it'll only work for your project: it's just a little fix that doesn't treat the source of your problem, it just gives you the effect you want. He took your debug values and do `size / cCollider.radius` ~= 0.0135394121 / 0.09026274 ~= 0.15

In order to make it work do this:

```
float magicNumber = 1f / 0.15f;
```

(Sorry to use an Answer whereas it should be a comment, I need to gain reputation to do that)